# If I use a Python socket over localhost, are there security concerns I need to be aware of?

Tags: webserver, server, tcp, python, websocket

I am implementing a simple [socket](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) in Python to pass data back and forth between two scripts running on the same machine (unfortunately, a socket is the only possible setup for my situation).

This data, in many cases, will be highly sensitive (i.e. personal credit card numbers).

**Does passing the data between scripts in this way open me up to any security concerns?**

Server side:

```
import socket

serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serversocket.bind(('localhost', 8089))
serversocket.listen(5) # become a server socket, maximum 5 connections

while True:
    connection, address = serversocket.accept()
    buf = connection.recv(64)
    if len(buf) > 0:
        print buf
        break
```

Client side:

```
import socket

clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientsocket.connect(('localhost', 8089))
clientsocket.send('hello')
```

[Code source.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18297623/1318135)

Comment: If you're on a *nix system I'd use unix sockets and make the file permission as restrictive as possible. Why is this the only possible setup?

Comment: It needs to run on Windows 7 as well. There's a better discussion on the Python mailing list, but that's not linkable. You can, in part, see the reasons in the comments to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46802154/1318135

Comment: The two scripts will always run on the same machine to exchange data or do you expect them to run over network

Comment: The problem is, that each user and thus process could connect to these sockets, if you do not add authentication and encryption. This is why @AndrolGenhald suggested to use sockets.

Comment: @Ubaidah they will always run on the same machine. Never over a network.

Comment: @cornelinux I am already using sockets. Is there potential for other users in this use case? Is authentication and encryption available here?

Comment: why would you want to encrypt it if it's all on the same machine? if you need to encrypt it to keep it safe, you obviously have FAR bigger problems. just validate the request and you're golden

Comment: I would use the address form 127.0.0.1 or ::1 which is _required_ to be handled locally and not sent out; the name form localhost _should_ do this but people sometimes change it (and sometimes even have arguably sane reasons to).

Comment: @user1318135 You would have to implement authentication and encryption yourself in your python script.

Comment: @dandavis Is this approach what you mean by validation? https://stackoverflow.com/a/45988256/1318135

Comment: @user1318135: yes, once you know it's local, you can assume trust. well, hopefully ;)

Comment: if you assume the machine is physically secure and only authorized user has access to it then your method is OK. But if you are saying that someone unauthorized to access the data could physically or remotely access the machine then your problem is bigger and outside the scope of the script, you are working on.

Comment: Anyway, you could use SSL and TLS I think the IPCN model in python support that. IPCN Interprocess Communication and Networking

Answer (score 1):

**This is completely insecure in *local-machine multi-user* scenarios.** For example, suppose your system runs on a Windows box that is domain-joined and allows any member of the domain to log into the machine, or a Linux network that allows other people to SSH in (both configurations are common in corporate environments). Even **without admin/root access**, anybody who can run code on the machine can open their own socket listener on port 8089 if the "official" listener isn't running, or can send traffic to the official listener if the client isn't using up all the connection slots. Either of these scenarios opens the system up to compromise of the network traffic.

A local network attacker can also attempt to compromise the client or server, crashing them (which may then let them stand up their own in its place, even with just a crash) or possibly even gaining code execution as the service account (for example, if one part has a command injection vulnerability). This could potentially enable the attacker to not only steal the information the service is meant to handle, but also gain access to other restricted areas while masking who is actually accessing the system.

The correct approach here is to use a secure IPC mechanism, one that allows access controls and provides connection confidentiality. The two that are closest to loopback TCP sockets are Unix domain (local) sockets on *nix-based systems, and Windows named pipes on Windows-based systems. Many socket-based libraries and frameworks already support these - for example, Node's `server` module is perfectly happy to listen on a local socket or named pipe - so it might be an easier change than you're expecting. You could also switch to a SSL/TLS connection that supports mutual client-server auth, such as using a client certificate or a pre-shared key (and of course validating that the server certificate is one that only the legitimate server process has access to), but that's likely a more complicated change that is easier to get wrong, compared to using a communication channel that was designed from the start for security.

Comment: ... *or a Linux network that allows other people to SSH in*. Your blind open-source zealotry and lack of reading comprehension say some unfortunate things about you, @Ubaidah. Go troll somewhere else more suited to your level of "discourse", OK?

Comment: I am very sorry I did not mean to offend you in any way. In fact, I like your answer that is why I added a comment.